# eww ---> libxml2 library not found

Tags: microsoft-windows, install, eww

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1.

I try to open in Emacs some web page. E.g. **www.google.com**.

So `M-x eww`

```
Enter URL: www.google.com
```

But I get error: `libxml2 library not found`

Answer (score 10):

As @Drew noted, Emacs doesn't include this library so on Windows you need to install it separately.

See the Emacs README.w32 section "Optional dependency libraries" for more information. As of Emacs 25 it looks like you can download the dependencies from the GNU FTP server (or a mirror). E.g. http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-25-x86_64-deps.zip

This is the easiest way to go: download the appropriate emacs-deps zip file and extract it over the top of your emacs installation.

You can also download the necessary libraries from https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports, or install msys2. If you go that route you'll need to decide which libraries you need -- libxml2, gnutls, etc.

However you choose to obtain the libraries, I've found it easiest to copy the dlls to your emacs/bin dir. The README.w32 suggests you can just add the dir containing the dlls to your PATH but I recall not having that work for me in the past.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `libxml2` is an optional package that you can install along with Emacs.  It is the XML support library, and required for HTML and XML support in
Emacs.

For Microsoft Windows 64-bit Emacs, the file `nt/INSTALL.w64` says this:

> ** Download and install the necessary packages
>
> Run `msys2_shell.bat` in your `MSYS2` directory and you will see a BASH window
>     opened.
>
> In the BASH prompt, use the following command to install the necessary
>     packages (you can copy and paste it into the shell with `Shift + Insert`):
>
> ```
>    pacman -S base-devel \
>    mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain \
>    mingw-w64-x86_64-xpm-nox \
>    mingw-w64-x86_64-libtiff \
>    mingw-w64-x86_64-giflib \
>    mingw-w64-x86_64-libpng \
>    mingw-w64-x86_64-libjpeg-turbo \
>    mingw-w64-x86_64-librsvg \
>    mingw-w64-x86_64-libxml2 \
>    mingw-w64-x86_64-gnutls \
>    mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib
> ```