# Unable to run nov-mode on Windows

Tags: package, debugging, microsoft-windows

disclaimer: I'm still relatively new to Emacs.

When I open an Epub on MS Windows, Emacs opens it using Zip-Archive mode and displays its content (which is normal afaik).

[image]

However, when I start `nov-mode`, encoded characters are displayed and I got an error of `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil` in the minibuffer.

[image]

What should I do? Where should I look?

---

**EDIT**
You can find [sources of nov here](https://github.com/wasamasa/nov.el)

Comment: Please add a reference (with link) to something that describes `nov-mode`. Please turn on `debug-on-error` and show the backtrace you get. Preferably load the relevant source file first, so the backtrace is more detailed/clear.

Comment: The most common issue Windows users reported to me is that they haven't customized `nov-unzip-program` to the location of an `unzip` executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things were actually missing:
- `libxml2` dependency
- proper setting of `nov-unzip-program`

I could add `libxml2` the easy way by going to [Emacs FTP](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/), download the dependencies, and apply them in my Emacs installation directory.

For the set of `nov-unzip-program` I had to download [Unzip for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/unzip.htm), and set the path in `init.el`:
`(setq nov-unzip-program "C:\\My\\Path\\To\\unzip.exe")`

Comment: How to download dependency is explained in [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34007/eww-libxml2-library-not-found)